# Mac 10.8 > Cannot encode text file with UTF8

Tags: macos, encoding, utf-8

I cannot have a text or php file with utf8 charset ! I tried Netbeans, PhpStorm, iconv CLI etc... still file charset = us-ascii :

```
iconv -f us-ascii -t utf-8 toto.php > toto2.php
file -I toto2.php
toto2.php: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
```

What can I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the content of `toto2.php`?

If the file only contains ASCII-compatible characters (i.e. mostly latin and the few "common" special characters), then there's no way for `file` (or any other tool) to distinguish a ASCII-encoded and an UTF-8 encoded file, because they will be byte-for-byte identical.

Given that `iconv` converted from "us-ascii", that's actually a given!

In other words: converting from a (real) ASCII file to a UTF-8 file is a no-op!

Comment: Ho thanks ! It was pure php code, but I tried to add some accent and get charset=utf8 finally !

Comment: You're welcome. If you find the answer helped you, feel free to express that in any way ;-)

Comment: Thanks you for the real explanation, all stackoverflow post just mention "file -bi" or "iconv" without explain why ...